# Kubernetes using secrets in pod

Tags: kubernetes

I have a spring boot app image which needs the following property.

server.ssl.keyStore=/certs/keystore.jks

I am loading the keystore file to secrets using the bewloe command.

kubectl create secret generic ssl-keystore-cert --from-file=./server-ssl.jks

I use the below secret reference in my deployment.yaml

```
           {
            "name": "SERVER_SSL_KEYSTORE",
            "valueFrom": {
              "secretKeyRef": {
                "name": "ssl-keystore-cert",
                "key": "server-ssl.jks"
              }
            }
          }
```

With the above reference, I am getting the below error.

> Error: failed to start container "app-service": Error response from
>   daemon: oci runtime error: container_linux.go:265: starting container
>   process caused "process_linux.go:368: container init caused \"setenv:
>   invalid argument\"" Back-off restarting failed container

If i go with the volume mount option,

```
"spec": {
        "volumes": [
          {
            "name": "keystore-cert",
            "secret": {
              "secretName": "ssl-keystore-cert",
              "items": [
                {
                  "key": "server-ssl.jks",
                  "path": "keycerts"
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        ],
        "containers": [
          {
            "env": [
              {
                "name": "JAVA_OPTS",
                "value": "-Dserver.ssl.keyStore=/certs/keystore/keycerts"
              }
            ],
            "name": "app-service",
            "ports": [
              {
                "containerPort": 8080,
                "protocol": "TCP"
              }
            ],
            "volumeMounts": [
              {
                "name": "keystore-cert",
                "mountPath": "/certs/keystore"
              }
            ],
            "imagePullPolicy": "IfNotPresent"
          }
        ]
```

I am getting the below error with the above approach.

> Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Resource location must
>   not be null   at
>   org.springframework.util.Assert.notNull(Assert.java:134)
>   ~[spring-core-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.7.RELEASE]  at
>   org.springframework.util.ResourceUtils.getURL(ResourceUtils.java:131)
>   ~[spring-core-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.7.RELEASE]  at
>   org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.jetty.JettyEmbeddedServletContainerFactory.configureSslKeyStore(JettyEmbeddedServletContainerFactory.java:301)
>   ~[spring-boot-1.4.5.RELEASE.jar!/:1.4.5.RELEASE]

I tried with the below option also, instead of JAVA_OPTS,

```
{
                "name": "SERVER_SSL_KEYSTORE",
                "value": "/certs/keystore/keycerts"
              }
```

Still the error is same.

Not sure what is the right approach.

Comment: Secret and deployment looks fine to me (on mount option), Could you check if the `/certs/keystore/keycerts` exists after container start? and on the environment variable change it to: `-Dserver.ssl.keyStore=file:///certs/keystore/keycerts` or `-Dserver.ssl.keyStore=file:/certs/keystore/keycerts`

Comment: I tried both. No error this time, but dont see anyhting in the logs as the server is not starting. "The selected container has not logged any messages yet."

Comment: Okey, whats the container status in the pod? is it restarting or its up? if its up `ls /certs/keystore/` to check the secret mount is actually working

Comment: Pod status is running.

Comment: try to `kubectl describe pod $podname`  you will find some logs in the end of explanation of pod.

Comment: Warning  Failed                 4m (x5 over 6m)   kubelet, minikube  Error: failed to start container "eos-service": Error response from daemon: oci runtime error: container_linux.go:265: starting container process caused "process_linux.go:368: container init caused \"setenv: invalid argument\""
  Warning  BackOff                1m (x22 over 5m)  kubelet, minikube  Back-off restarting failed container

Answer (score 3):

I tried to repeat the situation with your configuration. I created a secret used command:

```
kubectl create secret generic ssl-keystore-cert --from-file=./server-ssl.jks
```

I used this YAML as a test environment:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: busybox
  namespace: default
spec:
  containers:
  - image: busybox
    command:
      - sleep
      - "3600"
    imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
    name: busybox
    env:
    - name: JAVA_OPTS
      value: "-Dserver.ssl.keyStore=/certs/keystore/server-ssl.jks"
    ports:
    - containerPort: 8080
      protocol: TCP
    volumeMounts:
    - name: secret-volume
      readOnly: true
      mountPath: "/cert/keystore"
  volumes:
  - name: secret-volume
    secret:
      secretName: ssl-keystore-cert
```

As you see, I used "server-ssl.jks" file name in the variable. If you create the secret from a file, Kubernetes will store this file in the secret. When you mount this secret to any place, you just store the file. You tried to use `/certs/keystore/keycerts` but it doesn't exist, which you see in logs:

> Resource location must not be null at org.springframework.util.Assert.notNull

Because your mounted secret is here `/certs/keystore/keycerts/server-ssl.jks`

It should work, but just fix the paths